# Max div height in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

How can I have a div of static 60px height in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Please, think *very* carefully before writing code that only works in one browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="height: 60px; overflow: hidden;">Hello, World</div>
```

Some versions of IE don't follow max-height, unfortunately, and that's where `overflow: hidden` comes in handy. Note that the div will ALWAYS have 60px height no matter what's inside it.

Answer (score 3):

```
#el {
    height:expression(this.scrollHeight>59?"60px":"auto");     
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Why is there scrollHeight instead of just height?

Comment: "An element's scrollHeight is a measurement of the height of an element's content including content not visible on the screen due to overflow." - I'm sure clientHeight could also be used as well but I thought maybe this was necessary.

Comment: Expressions no longer work in IE9 and I thought they no longer worked in IE8 so this is a horrible idea.

Comment: expressions are CPU hoggers, stay away from them if you can http://blog.dynatrace.com/2010/02/16/the-real-performance-overhead-of-css-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height: 60px;">This is my div</div>
```

Comment: If the contents are bigger then 60px, the div will auto-resize.